# How can you change the render format?

Tags: rendering

So, i made a temple and wanted to render it. I changed the default settings of the aspect ratio ( after looking up how to do that). Everything seemed fine, but when i finally render it, the image is squashed. What did I do wrong?[image: how it should look]
this is how it should look...

[image: squashed]

and this is the squashed looking render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed the aspect ratio when you shouldn't have. Change it back to the default setting (X: 1.0, Y: 1.0) and the render will turn out like the preview. Think of the setting as the aspect ratio of the individual pixels, not of the entire image.